# ElasticSearch - Find documents where different fields have the same value

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find documents in my index which are related to each other.

In my case, it is by field A of Doc1 having the same value as field B of Doc2.

Note: I am forced to use ES 5.6.16 so no sql is available :(

I have the following data in my index:

```
{
    {

        "_type": "item",

        "_itemId": "i_1"

    }

    {

        "_type": "item",

        "_itemId": "i_2"

    }

    {

        "_type": "relation",

        "_relId": "r_1",

        "_relatedId": "i_1"

    }

    {

        "_type": "relation",

        "_relId": "r_2",

        "_relatedId": "i_1"

    }

    {

        "_type": "relation",

        "_relId": "r_3",

        "_relatedId": "i_2"

    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
"item": {
    "_itemId": {
    "type": "keyword"
    }
}

"incoming": {
    "_relatedId": {
    "type": "keyword"
    }
}
```

Now I want to find all docs where _itemId and _relatedId are matching.

I was trying:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
      "dups": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "_itemId"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "b_hits": {
            "top_hits": {
             "_source": "_relatedId"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

My desired output was (pseudo):

{i_1, r_1, r_2}

{i_2, r_3}

But I was only getting i_* as a result.

Comment: How does your mapping look like? Can you change it if needed?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. Edited the descripton. It looks like this: _itemId{ type: "keyword" },

_relatedId{ type: "keyword" }. Or which part of the mapping are you interested in?

Comment: Take a look at [has_child]( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) I would give you a full example, but if you cannot be bothered to format your question properly I don't really feel like spending more time answering it. Sorry.